# Problem with package structure? Hokuyo not working

Tags: ros, urg-node, hokuyo, hokuyo-laser, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

Sry I can't find a good question name for this :(

I made the last days my first approach of my very first own package. So i looked up a little bit in the forum and found something I could use. I wanted to publish some laser data from my hokuyo laser. So not really publish I just want to print it on my console.
Yesterday I made it to work, but today i started my pc and nothing worked so far. You can review the "package" here [link to github](https://github.com/schultza/hokuyo_test).

As I said it my very first test but somehow if I let it run via eclipse nothing happens. The hokuyo itself works I can connect with it via `rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"`. I just cant figure out what happend maybe some problems in my structure or in my CMakeLists.txt or smth like this? maybe you can help me.

Edit:

1. mkdir -p ~/new_hokuyo_test/src
2. cd ~/new_hokuyo_test/src/
3. catkin_init_workspace
   3.* cd ..
4. catkin_make
5. cd src/
6. catkin_create_pkg hokuyo_test_pkg std_msgs roscpp rospy
7. cd ~/new_hokuyo_test/
8. catkin_make
9. Uncommented some stuff (like add executable etc) in CMakeLists.txt (see github)
10. catkin_make (just to test)
11. added hokuyo_test_pkg_node.cpp in src of hokuyo_test_pkg
12. catkin_make in ws directory
13. source devel/setup.bash
14. rosrun hokuyo_test_pkg hokuyo_test_pkg_node

Thats it basically

Edit2: The launch file

```
<launch>
<node pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" name="urg_node"> 
<param name="ip_address" value="192.168.0.10" />
</node>
<node pkg="hokuyo_test_pkg" type="hokuyo_test_pkg_node" name="hokuyo_test_pkg_node" output="screen">
</node>
</launch>
```

Thanks for helping me, I know these are really beginner questions but anyways I am struggling with it and really try by myself to solve it and dont (maybe looks like :) ) post it instantly here. So Thank you for great help here

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203784/problem-with-package-structure?-hokuyo-not-working/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-26**:
Please update your question description with the exact steps that you are using to build your workspace and run your node.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-26**:
Also: we normally only commit the package directory itself to a github repository, *not* the entire catkin workspace (and especially not the `devel` directory). We can recreate the workspace and build it ourselves quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> mkdir -p ~/new_hokuyo_test/src
> cd ~/new_hokuyo_test/src/
> ```

ok.

> ```
> catkin_init_workspace
> ```

you don't need this, `catkin_make` will do all that is needed for you on first invocation.

> ```
> catkin_make
> ```

I think you forgot a `cd ..` before `catkin_make`?

> ```
> cd src/
> catkin_create_pkg hokuyo_test_pkg std_msgs roscpp rospy
> cd ~/new_hokuyo_test/
> catkin_make
>
> # Uncommented some stuff (like add executable etc) in CMakeLists.txt (see github)
>
> catkin_make (just to test)
> added `hokuyo_test_pkg_node.cpp` in `src` of `hokuyo_test_pkg`
> catkin_make in ws directory
> source devel/setup.bash
> rosrun hokuyo_test_pkg hokuyo_test_pkg_node
> ```

And at this point you have the `urg_node` already running in another terminal? And a `roscore`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2015-02-26**:
No the `cd ..` i just forgot to write it. edited. I got an roscore running yea, but not the urg_node is it needed? I tried it with urg node running (`rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"`) But didnt make any diffrence. The node which i wrote strat but there are no prints

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-26**:
How do you expect your test node to print anything, if there is no node that publishes those `LaserScan` messages? So yes, you need to start all three: `roscore`, `urg_node` and your own node. You might want to use a launch file for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-26**:
After you've started the `urg_node`, use `rostopic list` in another terminal (where you've also sourced `devel/setup.bash`) to see if it is actually publishing on the topic you expect. If it is, use `rostopic echo /TOPIC_NAME` to make sure there are actually msgs being published.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2015-02-26**:
You are right :) I started the urg_node which is publishing the /scan (which I am want to subscribe to) and also others like /echoes. So if I `rostopic echo /scan` I dont see anything, however if I `rostopic echo /echoes` I can see some data

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2015-02-26**:
So ok, somehow it works, I didnt change anything. :( Can't explain why, maybe I missed starting the urd_node sometimes or started the other node too early. Anyways I am happy that its working now. Thank you for your help!!! There is one thing left,I dont know if I should open a new question for this

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2015-02-26**:
I tried writing the launch file you mentioned. But it doesnt find my node: Error message here: `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hokuyo_test_pkg/hokuyo_test_package_node]: can't locate node [hokuyo_test_package_node] in package [hokuyo_test_pkg]` I added the launch file in the question

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2015-02-27**:
Okay found it already got a big typo in launch file

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-27**:
Ok, good to hear that you found it. Question answered? :)

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2015-02-27**:
yes :) Thank you very much for help an patience :)